# Inserting a row when a foreign key doesn't have a value to refer to

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert, create-table

I'm trying to build a forum website and design comment database schema. It's what I wrote. The problem is when I post comment, I get this error. 
(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`reddit`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`parentID`) REFERENCES `comments` (`commentID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)')
I understand why I get this error but I'm not sure how to fix it. I wanna solve it without creating a new replies table if possible. Is there a way to add a comment, which isn't a reply, with its parentID set to zero or other value that indicates it's not a reply?

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    commentID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    postID INT NOT NULL,
    parentID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    createdAt DATETIME NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(commentID),
    FOREIGN KEY(postID) REFERENCES posts(postID)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(parentID) REFERENCES comments(commentID)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES users(username)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
 )
```

Comment: Try nullable `parentID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL supports nullable foreign keys, and I think that’s the relevant option here.

So, just make the `parent_id` column `null`able, that is remove the `not null` option from the definition of that column (or change or to `NULL` - that’s default value when the option is missing).

You can then ignore this column when inserting (or pass a `NULL` value), to represent the absence of a parent comment.